# What's the best way to store date in spring boot jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

what's the best way of storing database date in spring boot entity?

For example, in my db I need to store smth like `2021-02-19 17:00` and then build queries on this date in my spring boot applicaiton

Comment: Consider using `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how can I filter my data using Repository interface with LocalDateTime?

Comment: It really depends on the exact query.  You haven't provided any information on what you plan to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry. Just need query that checks if date in between two dates?

Comment: Yes; create two `LocalDateTime` in your service method, then bind them to a prepared statement in the repository method.

Comment: Here's exactly what you are looking for https://vladmihalcea.com/date-timestamp-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Given that that’s meant to define a point in time use `timestamp with time zone` (or equivalent) in your database and `OffsetDateTime` in Java. It’s a bit funny that you should use `OffsetDateTIme`, but it works smoothly with `timestamp with time zone`, and you can always convert to and from other types in Java. Only don’t use the `LocalDateTime`class suggested by others because it does *not* define a point in time.

Comment: @OleV.V. can't I just use ```ZonedDateTime``` with ```timestamp```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalDateTime and the appropriate date column type in the database. Then you will be able to easily do date math (e.g. comparison) both in a database query and in Java if necessary.

Comment: BTW, I would generally not use LocalDateTime either, but the question was specifically about storing a date and time with no timezone info, and I still contend that LocalDateTime is appropriate for that. In most cases, you would want a timezone, and hence would want a ZonedDateTime, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek so, can I just use ZonedDateTime in Entity class like
```@Column(name="time") private ZonedDateTime time;```? Or it's require some JSON serializer options to rewrite

BTW I use postgresql

Comment: Yes, but there are caveats. See for example, https://thorben-janssen.com/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/

Comment: I seem to be getting `A table can only have one timestamp column.` for using multiple LocalDateTime Column. Any ideas to fix this ?

Comment: @Mahesh try a different column type.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store date as string in your database you have many options, but answering to which one is better in my opinion it completely depends on your database and your mapping strategy, for example consider

```html
DateTimeFormatter firstFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd, MMM, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.NOVEMBER, 7);
String firstDateAsString = firstFormatter.format(date);
System.out.println(firstDateAsString);
```

Which first `firstFormatter.formate()` accepts TemporalAccessor, as an other example

```html
DateFormat secondFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String secondDateAsString= secondFormatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println(secondDateAsString);
```

Note that the hibernate query payload and execution time will depends completely on your mapping and tokenizing the string accumulated by date.

Comment: (1) The question said *in my db I need to store smth like `2021-02-19 17:00`*. You can’t fit that into your snippets (2) if this answer does fulfil someone’s needs, the first snippet is the one to go with. It is strongly recommended not to use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are notoriously troublesome and long outdated.